# Is there a free cross-platform IDE that will except the Air SDK 3.4 and package HTML5/CSS3 documents to EXE?

Tags: html, css, windows-7, air, ide

I'm running two systems, one Linux and another Windows 7. I need a **FREE** IDE that could work on either platform which can use the new Adobe Air SDK (3.4 at the time of this question) and package the project as a windows executable.

I'm currently using Aptana 2.0 with the old Air SDK 1.5, however, this does not recognize HTML5 / CSS3.

I have tried so far;
Eclipse Juno, nothing...
Aptana 3.0, nothing...
Titanium Studio, nothing...

If you need to know the reason, I need to make a local app that will run on windows and no, I don't want it to run locally in a browser.

I've also searched the net. If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest Adobe AIR SDK with Aptana Studio 2.0.

1. Download the latest Adobe AIR SDK and extract its contents to the "plugins" directory which is within the Aptana Studio program directory.
2. Open Aptana and go to the "Window" menu and select "Preferences".
3. Expand the "Aptana" menu item in the sidebar and select "AIR SDKs".
4. Click on the "Add" button.
5. Click the "Browse" button and select the directory which you extracted to your "plugins" directory at Step 1, and then supply a name for the SDK eg. "Adobe AIR SDK 3.4".
6. Click "OK" to save.
7. Click "OK" again to dismiss the Preferences window.

Now you have successfully installed the latest Adobe AIR SDK.

Now you will want to run your project with the latest Adobe AIR SDK which you have just installed so:

1. Go to the "Run" menu and select "Run Configurations...".
2. Where it says "Adobe AIR SDK", select from the drop down the version of the SDK which you would like to run your project with.